# Make Span Class Responsive + Spacing between divs

Tags: html, css

Im currently making a site, and I had a problem with viewing my element with Mobiles.

A little bit of it bugs out of the screen, which makes it look horrible.

This the element code:

```
<span class="irs js-irs-0  irs-with-grid">
  <span class="irs"><span class="irs-line" tabindex="0">
    <span class="irs-line-left"></span><span class="irs-line-mid">
    </span><span class="irs-line-right"></span>
    </span><span class="irs-min" style="visibility: hidden;">1 000</span>
    <span class="irs-max" style="visibility: visible;">1 000 000</span>
    <span class="irs-from" style="visibility: hidden;">0</span>
    <span class="irs-to" style="visibility: hidden;">0</span>
    <span class="irs-single" style="left: -5.25972%;">6 000</span>
  </span><span class="irs-grid" style="width: 95.9184%; left: 1.94082%;">
  <span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 0%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-0" style="left: 0%; margin-left: -3.69898%;">1 000</span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 20%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 15%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 10%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 5%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 25%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-1" style="left: 25%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -4.97449%;">250 750</span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 45%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 40%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 35%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 30%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 50%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-2" style="left: 50%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -5.10204%;">500 500</span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 70%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 65%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 60%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 55%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 75%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-3" style="left: 75%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -5.10204%;">750 250</span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 95%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 90%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 85%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 80%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 100%"></span>
  <span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-4" style="left: 100%; margin-left: -5.9949%;">1 000 000</span>
  </span><span class="irs-bar" style="left: 2.04082%; width: 0.480072%;"></span><span class="irs-bar-edge"></span>
  <span class="irs-shadow shadow-single" style="display: none;"></span>
  <span class="irs-slider single" style="left: 0.480072%;"></span>
</span>
```

CSS Files:

```
    /* Ion.RangeSlider
    // css version 2.0.3
    // © 2013-2014 Denis Ineshin | IonDen.com
    // ===================================================================================================================*/

    /* =====================================================================================================================
    // RangeSlider */

    .irs {
        position: relative; display: block;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
         -khtml-user-select: none;
           -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
    }
        .irs-line {
            position: relative; display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            outline: none !important;
        }
            .irs-line-left, .irs-line-mid, .irs-line-right {
                position: absolute; display: block;
                top: 0;
            }
            .irs-line-left {
                left: 0; width: 11%;
            }
            .irs-line-mid {
                left: 9%; width: 82%;
            }
            .irs-line-right {
                right: 0; width: 11%;
            }

        .irs-bar {
            position: absolute; display: block;
            left: 0; width: 0;
        }
            .irs-bar-edge {
                position: absolute; display: block;
                top: 0; left: 0;
            }

        .irs-shadow {
            position: absolute; display: none;
            left: 0; width: 0;
        }

        .irs-slider {
            position: absolute; display: block;
            cursor: default;
            z-index: 1;
        }
            .irs-slider.single {

            }
            .irs-slider.from {

            }
            .irs-slider.to {

            }
            .irs-slider.type_last {
                z-index: 2;
            }

        .irs-min {
            position: absolute; display: block;
            left: 0;
            cursor: default;
        }
        .irs-max {
            position: absolute; display: block;
            right: 0;
            cursor: default;
        }

        .irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-single {
            position: absolute; display: block;
            top: 0; left: 0;
            cursor: default;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

    .irs-grid {
        position: absolute; display: none;
        bottom: 0; left: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 20px;
    }
    .irs-with-grid .irs-grid {
        display: block;
    }
        .irs-grid-pol {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; left: 0;
            width: 1px; height: 8px;
            background: #000;
        }
        .irs-grid-pol.small {
            height: 4px;
        }
        .irs-grid-text {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0; left: 0;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 9px; line-height: 9px;
            padding: 0 3px;
            color: #000;
        }

    .irs-disable-mask {
        position: absolute; display: block;
        top: 0; left: -1%;
        width: 102%; height: 100%;
        cursor: default;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .irs-disabled {
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    .lt-ie9 .irs-disabled {
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    }


    .irs-hidden-input {
        position: absolute !important;
        display: block !important;
        top: 0 !important;
        left: 0 !important;
        width: 0 !important;
        height: 0 !important;
        font-size: 0 !important;
        line-height: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        outline: none !important;
        z-index: -9999 !important;
        background: none !important;
        border-style: solid !important;
        border-color: transparent !important;
    }
    /* Ion.RangeSlider, Flat UI Skin
    // css version 2.0.3
    // © Denis Ineshin, 2014    https://github.com/IonDen
    // ===================================================================================================================*/

    /* =====================================================================================================================
    // Skin details */

    .irs-line-mid,
    .irs-line-left,
    .irs-line-right,
    .irs-bar,
    .irs-bar-edge,
    .irs-slider {
        background: url(../img/sprite-skin-flat.png) repeat-x;
    }

    .irs {
        height: 40px;
    }
    .irs-with-grid {
        height: 60px;
    }
    .irs-line {
        height: 12px; top: 25px;
    }
        .irs-line-left {
            height: 12px;
            background-position: 0 -30px;
        }
        .irs-line-mid {
            height: 12px;
            background-position: 0 0;
        }
        .irs-line-right {
            height: 12px;
            background-position: 100% -30px;
        }

    .irs-bar {
        height: 12px; top: 25px;
        background-position: 0 -60px;
    }
        .irs-bar-edge {
            top: 25px;
            height: 12px; width: 9px;
            background-position: 0 -90px;
        }

    .irs-shadow {
        height: 3px; top: 34px;
        background: #000;
        opacity: 0.25;
    }
    .lt-ie9 .irs-shadow {
        filter: alpha(opacity=25);
    }

    .irs-slider {
        width: 16px; height: 18px;
        top: 22px;
        background-position: 0 -120px;
    }
    .irs-slider.state_hover, .irs-slider:hover {
        background-position: 0 -150px;
    }

    .irs-min, .irs-max {
        color: #999;
        font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.333;
        text-shadow: none;
        top: 0; padding: 1px 3px;
        background: #e1e4e9;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-single {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.333;
        text-shadow: none;
        padding: 1px 5px;
        background: #ed5565;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .irs-from:after, .irs-to:after, .irs-single:after {
        position: absolute; display: block; content: "";
        bottom: -6px; left: 50%;
        width: 0; height: 0;
        margin-left: -3px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #ed5565;
    }


    .irs-grid-pol {
        background: #e1e4e9;
    }
    .irs-grid-text {
        color: #999;
    }

    .irs-disabled {
    }
/*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

/**
 * 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
    font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove default margin.
 */

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct `block` display not defined for any HTML5 element in IE 8/9.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `details` or `summary` in IE 10/11
 * and Firefox.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `main` in IE 11.
 */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
    display: block;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Normalize vertical alignment of `progress` in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */

audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
    display: inline-block; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address `[hidden]` styling not present in IE 8/9/10.
 * Hide the `template` element in IE 8/9/11, Safari, and Firefox < 22.
 */

[hidden],
template {
    display: none;
}

/* Links
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the gray background color from active links in IE 10.
 */

a {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9/10/11, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

/**
 * Address style set to `bolder` in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

b,
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in Safari and Chrome.
 */

dfn {
    font-style: italic;
}

/**
 * Address variable `h1` font-size and margin within `section` and `article`
 * contexts in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9.
 */

mark {
    background: #ff0;
    color: #000;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent and variable font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
    font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` affecting `line-height` in all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
    top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
    bottom: -0.25em;
}

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 8/9/10.
 */

img {
    border: 0;
}

/**
 * Correct overflow not hidden in IE 9/10/11.
 */

svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 8/9 and Safari.
 */

figure {
    margin: 1em 40px;
}

/**
 * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
 */

hr {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Contain overflow in all browsers.
 */

pre {
    overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * Address odd `em`-unit font size rendering in all browsers.
 */

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
    font-family: monospace, monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Known limitation: by default, Chrome and Safari on OS X allow very limited
 * styling of `select`, unless a `border` property is set.
 */

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited.
 *    Known issue: affects color of disabled elements.
 * 2. Correct font properties not being inherited.
 * 3. Address margins set differently in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
    color: inherit; /* 1 */
    font: inherit; /* 2 */
    margin: 0; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address `overflow` set to `hidden` in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */

button {
    overflow: visible;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Firefox, IE 8/9/10/11, and Opera.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox.
 */

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 4+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 4+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * It's recommended that you don't attempt to style these elements.
 * Firefox's implementation doesn't respect box-sizing, padding, or width.
 *
 * 1. Address box sizing set to `content-box` in IE 8/9/10.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9/10.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Fix the cursor style for Chrome's increment/decrement buttons. For certain
 * `font-size` values of the `input`, it causes the cursor style of the
 * decrement button to change from `default` to `text`.
 */

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    height: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari and Chrome on OS X.
 * Safari (but not Chrome) clips the cancel button when the search input has
 * padding (and `textfield` appearance).
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct `color` not being inherited in IE 8/9/10/11.
 * 2. Remove padding so people aren't caught out if they zero out fieldsets.
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * Don't inherit the `font-weight` (applied by a rule above).
 * NOTE: the default cannot safely be changed in Chrome and Safari on OS X.
 */

optgroup {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Tables
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
    padding: 0;
}
```

I want it to fit into the screen, so you dont have to scroll sidewards, how do I do that?

Is there also an Option to make a side gap, so that it doesnt exactly fit on to the edge.

And how can I make a gap between 2 divs?

Comment: Need more info to answer this question. Please include the CSS that goes with this. The code you provided just gives a pile of numbers on top of each other, which I'm guessing isn't the problem you're trying to fix. Please include enough code in your question that we can see how things look on your site right now, but no more than is necessary.

Comment: Added all CSS Files, hope you can help now :)

Comment: I dropped your code into CodePen and don't see a problem with side-scrolling: https://codepen.io/cjl750/pen/PKmxjg. You can drag the editor pane around to resize; I see the range area continuing to collapse onto itself no matter how small the screen gets, so if you're having trouble with it sticking out wider than the screen, there must be some other problem going on with the site's CSS. I added a couple quick styles at the top of the CSS you can use to include a little margin on either side of the whole thing, though.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/CG8oK

Comment: Now it works fine, thx very much

Comment: Ah. Your numbers were getting cut off, was that the problem? Yes, if you just shrink the width a bit, that will take care of it. Is that what you ended up doing?

Comment: yes, and also do u know how I make a little gap between 2 divs?

Comment: There are many possible answers to that question. Generally you could just give them a margin. Is there a specific instance you want me to look at?

Comment: Nope, made it in Margin, works fine

Comment: Great. I will post those things as an actual answer then.

Comment: Ye ill mark it as answered to get u some rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see by testing your code out that the range is perfectly responsive – it will shrink down as much as is necessary to fit on the screen – but you may have trouble with the numbers on the very left and very right getting cut off.

That is because those numbers are relatively positioned, and they are getting pushed farther to the side than they would normally appear.

The simple fix here that will also solve your problem of needing a little gap around the outside of the whole thing is to shrink the container, and then use a margin to center it.

The container is `span.irs-with-grid`, so that's what we'll target. As an example, if we want to put it at 95% width:

```
.irs-with-grid {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
}
```

The margin-left value comes from half the remaining value of the width of the screen. The container is 95% wide, meaning we have 5% of the screen's (or parent element's) width left over. So by setting our `margin-left` to half of 5%, we perfectly center the container.

You can adjust those values to whatever specific numbers you think look good.

As for creating a space between two divs, there are many options on how to do that that will depend on your particular situation, but margins are most commonly used for that purpose.